# attempted to read and write protected memory c# 2008 when deployment setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

In `C#` windows application,

When I run `vs2008` it is working properly but after creating Setup and then run any form is showing me error like below

> **System.accessviolationexception attempted to read or write protected memory. this is often an**

In this application I have been using Access database and `Crystal` report.

Please tell me what can be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.